# Did Rabbis in the Shtetl dip their shoes in water to travel on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, yiddish, literature

Edit: I was informed that this is found in one of Sholem Aleichem's books. If you could help me figure out which one, I would appreciate it.

I heard from someone I know that back in the Shtetl, Rabbis would dip their shoes in water in order to travel on Shabbat because there is not a restriction if you are at sea. I tried to find some information about this but couldn't. Did this happen, and if you are not sure, can you point me to somewhere where I could possibly investigate what rulings Rabbis made in European Shtetls throughout the ages.